# Angular Router will navigate to new view, but it will render inside the container of the previous view?

Tags: angular, routes

When I log in from URL/login

I have the following method

```js
this.router.navigate(['/home'])
```

It works, but for some reason, the new view is rendered inside the previous view container.

Visual representation of problem:

1. This is the components in the home's body:
   [Home's body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mdrr.png).
2. This is the login's body
   [Login's body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZd6N.png)
3. Instead of going back to show what is on the first image, I get this:
   [Home after redirect body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViUOU.png)

The first view has the two cards in a completely different place. When I get redirected from the login to the home component only one card ("How Does It Work") renders in the same place as the login's view card.

login.component.ts

```html
<p-card>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login()">
    <div class="p-fluid">
      <p-divider align="left" type="solid">
        <div class="p-d-inline-flex p-ai-center">
          <i class="pi pi-sign-in p-mr-2"></i>
        </div>
      </p-divider>
      <div class="p-field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input
          id="username"
          type="username"
          pInputText
          formControlName="username"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="p-field">
        <label>Password</label>
        <p-password formControlName="password" [feedback]="false"></p-password>
      </div>
      <button
        pButton
        pRipple
        type="submit"
        label="Login"
        icon="pi pi-angle-right"
        iconPos="right"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</p-card>
```

login.component.ts

```js
  login(): void {
    console.log(this.loginForm.getRawValue());
    this.userService.login(this.loginForm.getRawValue()).subscribe({
      next: data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.router.navigate(['/home'])
      },
      error: error =>{
        console.log("There was an error: " + error.message);
      }
    })
  }
```

user.module.ts (i have routing inside the module class, i will separate these later)

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to using primeng's ::ng-deep to override some of the CSS. This will make the changes global and other components will render with the same style. I solved this by using :host ::ng-deep rather than just :ng-deep by itself.